# C++ ReadFile Entirely, where size>2GB (Win64)

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Files show up in the 1.1GB-3.1GB range. Server has 64GB of RAM (The smaller servers have 24).

So I figure I'll just read the whole thing into memory instead of using chunks. (Chunks may land outside the crlf position so I'd have to backtrack a little. Much simpler code to just swallow the whole thing).

ReadFile and ReadFileEx seem stuck in 32-bit land, even when building in Win64. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "start\r\n";
    HANDLE hInput;
    hInput = CreateFile(L"My-giant-File.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    long long amountOfDataToRead = 4000000000; //Arbitrary 4Gb read buffer
    byte * buffer = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(malloc(amountOfDataToRead));

    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    ReadFile(hInput, buffer, amountOfDataToRead, &bytesRead, NULL);

    //Perform operation on data

    free(buffer);
    CloseHandle(hInput);

}
```

See above: bytesRead is a DWord. And I bet my input long long is just getting read as a long.

Comment: Reading in chunks doesn't imply processing in chunks...  In fact even if you pass the full file size to `ReadFile` for a 900 MB file, it's still internally going to read in chunks.

Comment: There is no question here. Does the code work? If not, how does it fail, and what do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadFile/Ex()` (and just I/O in general) is never guaranteed to read exactly as many bytes that you ask for. It may read less, so you have to be prepared to handle that possibility. That is why `ReadFile/Ex()` reports how many bytes it actually read. You need to take that into account by calling it in a loop to make sure you read everything you want, eg:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "start\r\n";
    HANDLE hInput = CreateFileW(L"My-giant-File.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    long long bufferSize = 4000000000LL; //Arbitrary 4Gb read buffer
    byte *buffer = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(malloc(bufferSize));

    byte *ptr = buffer;
    long long amountOfDataToRead = bufferSize;
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;

    while (amountOfDataToRead > 0) {
        if (!ReadFile(hInput, ptr, amountOfDataToRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
            // error handling...
            return -1;
        } 
        if (bytes_read == 0) {
            // unexpected eof...
            return -1;
        }
        ptr += bytesRead;
        amountOfDataToRead -= bytesRead;
    }

    //Perform operation on data

    free(buffer);
    CloseHandle(hInput);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: Why are you reading files of this size? Consider memory mapping them using `CreateFileMapping`/ `MapViewOfFile`.

Also, you can call `ReadFile` in a loop - not that you'd need to since a 3.1 GiB file is well within the range of a 32bit unsigned integer.